# How can I get all inputs from the closest tbody

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML form and I need to get the values of all inputs inside the closest `tbody` (there will be multiple `tbody` on page).  I would like to serialize the values and send to ajax.

So far my code is:

```
$(document).on('change', '.disguise', function (e) {
    //var params = $('').find('input').serialize(); // get all inputs from clicked row

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/calculateHours',
        data: params,
        success: function (response) {
            alert('Done...');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: `// get all inputs from clicked row` from clicked row or tbody???

Comment: @A.Wolff When using `closest` that doesn't matter as `closest` will return the element itself when used on `tbody`. So `$('tbody').closest('body')` is same as `$('tbody')`. And yes I also think, it'll be better if OP add HTML.

Comment: But row (`tr`) is different element than `tbody` which can contains multiple rows, so it is quite unclear what is expected regarding this comment: `get all inputs from clicked row` **and** `I need to get the values of all inputs inside the closest tbody`. This is what i meant

Comment: Yes, that is unclear, @V4n1ll4 Can you please add complete HTML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to get the values of all inputs inside the closest tbody

Use `closest()` and `find()`

```
var params = $(this).closest('tbody').find('input').serialize();
```

---

To select all the form elements use [:input](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector

```
var params = $(this).closest('tbody').find(':input').serialize();
```